# Is the sequence of partial sums $a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^i\frac{1}{i}$ Cauchy?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Is the sequence of partial sums $a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^i\frac{1}{i}$ Cauchy?
>
> How to prove it?

I think that the sequence is indeed Cauchy, but I cannot think of an elegant way to show it. At this point any way to show it will do.

Sorry of it is a trivial question.

Comment: Hint: Show if $m>n$ then $|a_{n}-a_{m}|<\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: You can show it indirectly by showing that your series converges.

Comment: Funny thing is that when I add this problem to a handout a year ago, I put in the solution the inequality you have, except I no longer remember its proof (or how to get it). #absentminded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refresh OP's memory: just figure out the sign of $a_n-a_m$ and group the terms in pairs.

If $m-n$ is odd:
$$
\begin{align}
|a_n-a_m|&=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}-\cdots-\frac{1}{m-1}+\frac{1}{m}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}-\left(\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right)-\cdots-\left(\frac{1}{m-1}-\frac{1}{m}\right)\\
&<\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$

If $m-n$ is even:
$$
\begin{align}
|a_n-a_m|&=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}-\cdots-\frac{1}{m-2}+\frac{1}{m-1}-\frac{1}{m}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}-\left(\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right)-\cdots-\left(\frac{1}{m-2}-\frac{1}{m-1}\right)-\frac{1}{m}\\
&<\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$